# What grains have been fermented?

Tags: fermentation

As i'm about to bottle my first batch.  After all the googling and reading I've done, what grains have been fermented into beer?

Comment: splitting this off into a grain by grain question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this list as a base for [grains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_grain#Classification), I will try to come up with list of grains that have been fermented into alcohol.  Everything in this list should be [possible](http://www.thebrewsite.com/apocalypse-beer-ferment-anything/) to ferment. The question is, has it?

## brewed

### Warm-season (C4) cereals

- [finger millet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusine_coracana#Nutrition) "The grain is made into a fermented drink (or beer) in Nepal and in
  many parts of Africa"
- [white fonio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonio#White_fonio_.28Digitaria_exilis.29) The grains are used in porridge and couscous, for bread, and for beer
- [foxtail millet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foxtail_millet) it's been [brewed](https://books.google.com/books?id=XAjXJU8Ud8sC&pg=PT271&lpg=PT271&dq=%22kodo+millet%22+fermentation+alcohol+beer&source=bl&ots=rvWVZ756QG&sig=-WTBsgVJkuIwwc0BzVFC34KNlNY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-f3TVI6iH4-INpTGgtAE&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22kodo%20millet%22%20fermentation%20alcohol%20beer&f=false) though i was looking for kodo millet at the time.
- [kodo millet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paspalum_scrobiculatum) potential answer .. though like foxtail millet, many cousins are fermented everywhere
- [japanese millet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinochloa_esculenta) someone [patented](http://www.google.com/patents/EP1867710A1?cl=en) a process to brew it
- [maize (corn)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maize)  yeah, didn't even read the wiki for *proof*
- [pearl millet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearl_millet#Namibia) namibia has it brewed
- [proso millet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proso_millet#Uses) yup, brewed.
- [sorghum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorghum) 30 sub-species on this one, will need to check each sub-species... stay tuned.

### Cool-season (C3) cereals

- [barley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barley) yeah....I'm a completionist. if you're reading this to see if it's been brewed do not invite me over to try your homebrew.
- [oats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oat) cook 'em first.
- [rice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice) ever drink a light beer?
- [rye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rye) brewing a rye pale ale right now, from a kit.
- [teff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragrostis_tef) gluten free beer, and amazing bread.
- [triticale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triticale) wheat meets rye. of course alcohol.
- [wheat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat) see rye.

### Pseudocereal grains

- [buckwheat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranth) ever had buckwheat pancakes? yeah brew it.
- [amaranth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranth) 44 species. stay tuned
- [quinoa](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120201924) patent for brewing it, apparently.

### Grain legumes or pulses

- [chickpeas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicha) Peruvian Chicha includes chickpeas
- [common beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaseolus_vulgaris) more species, stay tuned.
- [common peas (garden peas)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pea) [brewed](https://zythophile.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/pea-beer/)
- [lentils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lentil) brewed in [2012](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f36/wierd-idea-381968/index14.html) by boreal brewer
- [mung beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_bean) [patented](http://www.google.com/patents/CN1371967A?cl=en)
- [peanuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut) some evidence it's happened as a mistake, which i'll say they've been fermented by accident.
- pigeon peas see peas above.
- [runner beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaseolus_coccineus) yup [brewed](http://www.homewinemaking.co.uk/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1095679491)

### Aster family

- [safflower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safflower) used in a [yeast starter](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f128/brewing-ergosterol-safflower-oil-260886/index2.html), kind of counts...
- [sunflower seed](https://byo.com/hops/item/2530-brewing-gone-nuts) brewed.

### Other families

- [hemp seed (Hemp family)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemp)[not just for brownies anymore](http://hempgifts.com/hemp-beer/) not my thing, but it's been brewed.
- [poppy seed (Poppy family)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppy_seed#Use_in_food_and_cooking) [brewed](https://www.drugs-forum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=70837)

## no *proof* yet

### Warm-season (C4) cereals

- [black fonio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonio#Black_fonio_.28Digitaria_iburua.29) ... will research further
- [Raishan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonio#Raishan) ... will research further
- [Job's Tears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job%27s_Tears#Uses) turned into a liqour, though no specifications for beer.

### Pseudocereal grains

### Grain legumes or pulses

- [fava beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicia_faba) ... will research further
- [lima beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaseolus_lunatus) ... will research further
- [lupins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lupinus) ... will research further
- [soybeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soybean) forest through the trees again. fermented solids are everywhere, but in a brew? ... will research further

### Mustard family

- [black mustard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica_nigra) pretty much a spice and very oily. (ruins head, rots), in a wort?
- [India mustard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica_juncea) oily, a spice, in a wort? not that I found
- [rapeseed (including canola)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapeseed) um.. used for canola oil, chainsaw and steam engine lubricant. no evidence it's been brewed.

### Other families

- [flax seed (Flax family)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flax#Flax_seeds) yeah. oily.

Comment: +1 for the grains list.  Never would have thought to look for that.  Now I've got lots of new augments to try in the mash!  Mustard sounds interesting!!!!!  Great Answer!

Comment: This in no way answers the question, though.  Asking which grains haven't been fermented is like asking people in a room to raise their hand if they're not there.

Comment: @DennyConn agreed, proving a negative is impossible. Thinking of renaming the question to what Has been brewed.

Comment: And even then you still won't get a comprehensive list.  try to narrow it down a little more.

Comment: K.split it up grain by grain enough?  On my phone, making a wort and can't do it now:)